# C# how to use variable outside of block of code

Tags: c#

I have the following code. I want to use pictureBox1.Image = image outside of the code block like so:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

  using(MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) {
    pic.Image.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
    byte[] imageBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
  }

  Image image = Image.FromStream(memoryStream);
  pictureBox1.Image = image;
}
```

I get the folloowing error: The name 'memoryStream' does not exist in the current context. I know I can do the following move the last 2 lines into the brackets and the code works but How can I use variable outside of the { } block of code

I know the code below works but i just want to know if there is a way to use  pictureBox1.Image = image outside of the block of code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        pic.Image.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        byte[] imageBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        Image image = Image.FromStream(memoryStream);
        pictureBox1.Image = image;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the type of pictureBox1 ? where have you declared it ? Is it any type of control ?

Comment: *Why* do you want to write that line outside of the block? You don't actually need a `using` statement in the first place, since this is a memory stream. Even if you do, there are using declarations.

Answer (score 5):

You can't and shouldn't use the stream outside of the using scope, after that it will get disposed and you don't run into leaking issues.

You could just assign the value after the scope, when you declare the variable before it.

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Image image;
    using(MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        pic.Image.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        // byte[] imageBytes = memoryStream.ToArray(); //unused?
        image = Image.FromStream(memoryStream);
    }
    pictureBox1.Image = image;
}
```

Or better yet make a function to read the image and return it.

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Image = readImage();
}

private Image readImage()
{
    using(MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        pic.Image.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        // byte[] imageBytes = memoryStream.ToArray(); //unused?
        return Image.FromStream(memoryStream);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no problem putting that line outside the `using` block. The problem is line before. You can't use `memoryStream` outside the `using` block. The whole point of the `using` block is to create a scope for that variable and ensure that the object assigned to it is disposed at the end of the block. You can do this:

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Image image;

  using(MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) {
    pic.Image.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
    byte[] imageBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

    image = Image.FromStream(memoryStream);
  }

  pictureBox1.Image = image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define `MemoryStream outside the code  block`:

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
using (memoryStream)
{
   pic.Image.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
   byte[] imageBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
}

Image image = Image.FromStream(memoryStream);
pictureBox1.Image = image;
```

**Edit:(just for test)**

If you think `using` releases  all resources for the `variable defined outside`, test the following code:

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
using (memoryStream)
{
    byte[] messageBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("test Massage");
    memoryStream.Write(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length);
}
var data = Encoding.Default.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray()); // data = "test Massage"
```

Comment: I doubt this will work since `memoryStream` will be disposed after the `using` block.

Comment: That will probably throw an `ObjectDisposedException`

Comment: @Fildor I tested this method and it works correctly. You can also test...

Comment: At least that would be what is to be expected. In fiddle, a `ToArray()` did not throw. I found that odd and may be a speciality of MemoryStream. Wouldn' recommend to use _any_ type that is disposable after it has been disposed, though.

Comment: @Fildor The truth is, I didn't expect this method to work, but it works!